# How to add noise to supervised (binary-classifier)?

Tags: python, statistics, machine-learning-model, numpy

**Note**: The question is not about validating/testing a trained model.

Say i have an unlabeled features set, I want to approximate the true labels (for the sake of argument lets assume it's a binary classification prob).

I also have a trained model to predict the labels.
Now I want to use this model (since it is trained on the true labels, it should approx. my distribution)  along with some added noise (maybe gaussian) to generate the labels for this unknown dataset.
This should always result in a fixed effect size.

How can I do that? My features are mix of categorical and continuous values.

Would be awesome to illustrate the additive noise via python numpy package.

Apologies, I am a rookie!

Comment: What is it you are trying to achieve? the labels of the unlabeled features set? If so, why not using the predictive capability of the trained model? What purpose should the noising serve?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why/where you want to apply the noise, but if you want to add some Gaussian noise to a variable, you can do this:

```
import numpy as np

target_dims = your_target.shape
noise = np.random.rand(target_dims)
noisy_target = your_target + noise
```

Now use the `noisy_target` as input to your model.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I guess I am confused how to code this:
As I mentioned my features are mix of categorical and continuous values.
I don't understand how adding noise would work. It would be great if you give me an example, if you don't mind. To elaborate, what would be effect of Gaussian noise on categorical values.  

I also referred this post, which i similar to your solution.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46093073/adding-gaussian-noise-to-a-dataset-of-floating-points-and-save-it-python

Answer (score 0):

Adding noise to do pertubation of the data, to check the collinearity and multicollinearity in data to check whether we can use weight in Logistic Regression or not

```
dimesions = data.shape #to get the dimesion of the data
noise = np.random.rand(dimesion)
noisy_data = data + noise # to add noise the existing data
```

you can also use np.random.(A or B)
A=Normal
B=Uniform

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments and responses, it is unclear if noise is to be added to the features (some of which are categorical) or to the output preds.

- In case it is the former, I would strongly advice against pertubating the features directly, instead pertubate/add noise to the intermediate embeddings generated. There are libraries which do so.
- If it is generating distributions around the preds, you are looking at a PMMI models. Basically the embeddings (from a deep layer) are fed to the probabilistic model which then uses some priors to return the final preds.